# Does anyone know the brand on this bathroom faucet?

Tags: faucet, bathroom-fixtures

This faucet was here when we bought the house and we need to replace it but don’t know the brand/type. We’d like to replace with the same faucet if possible to match our other sinks. The previous owners tended to do things diy, and there’s no logo on the faucet that we could find.

[image: top view]
[image: front view]

Edit: adding picture of the back to show it doesn’t have a logo [image]

Comment: Look on the underside of the spout and handle(mirror or cell phone camera) as it might be marked there.

Comment: Unfortunately, there’s no indication of the brand there

Comment: look on the back side

Comment: Can you share why you're replacing it?

Comment: @JACK the aerator is broken in a way that it just can’t be removed. If you try to use a coin or pry it off, it doesn’t budge. We had a plumber look at it too and he said it was impossible to remove and we would be better off replacing it.